# How far does does this guy walk if he empties 24 barrow fulls and returns to the load each time?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is the 6th question in my assignment. It sounds quite confusing to me.
Here's the question:
A man moves a load of soil for top dressing an orchard by emptying barrow loads in a line 20 meters apart, with the first heap 20 meters from the load of soil. How far does he walk if he empties 24 barrow fulls and returns to the load each time?

Here's what I did:
[image: Working out for question 6]

I'm not too sure if this is correct.

Comment: Without knowing the capacity of a barrow (i.e. how many heaps can be made with just a barrow) it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He returns back implying it will be double the distance so AP will be $40,80..$ thus correct answer is $12000$